# footable scripts don't work for GridView in updatepanel after partial postback

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, updatepanel, footable

I am utilizing the footable (V2) scripts/CSS for an ASP.Net GridView (ASP.NET 4.5) in a webforms application to make the table responsive (resize and hide appropriate columns for different devices).
I would like the GridView to be inside an updatePanel for obvious reasons, however, on any partial postback, the footable scripts don't get executed (even though I put the script reference directly inside the UpdatePanel).
jQuery and Bootstrap scripts work just fine, however (go figure). 
The **footable_redraw** function does not help whether I load it w/ the built-in **pageLoad()** function or **$(document).ready** (or both) function.
I took the ToolkitScriptManager out of the MasterPage, but that makes no difference at all. I removed the ScriptReferences out of the TKSM to see if that would help, but it makes no difference. I tried hundreds of techniques from forums all around, but no answers have yet to work (and, suspiciously, no one has ever posted a complete working solution). Maybe this is simply not possible w/footable, I don't know.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/SiteBS.Master" CodeBehind="TestSearch1.aspx.vb" Inherits="SearchWebsite.TestSearch1" Async="True" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph1" runat="server">
    <%-- NOTE: putting the toolkitscriptmanager on the master page or this page, no difference. loadscriptsbeforeUI setting makes no difference
        jQuery and bootStrap are loaded via tags in the master page header, loading in TKSM makes no difference --%>
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="tksm1" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="False">
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div class="container">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">

            <ContentTemplate>
                <%-- NOTE: this script cannot go into scriptmanager as it will NOT WORK!!! Yet it won't work on partial postback --%>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/FooTable-2/dist/footable.min.js"></script>


                <%-- Set minimum column widths --%>
                <style type="text/css">
                    .hdrVdr { min-width: 80px; }
                    .hdrMan { min-width: 128px; }
                    .hdrCal { min-width: 88px; }
                    .hdrGW { min-width: 88px; }
                    .hdrProd { }
                    .hdrPrice { min-width: 108px; }
                    .hdrCR { min-width: 95px; }
                </style>


                <asp:GridView ID="grdHG" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="odsHGSearch" EnableViewState="False" CellPadding="1" AllowSorting="True">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor" SortExpression="vendor" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrVdr">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblVdr" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("vendor") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hididx" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("idx")%>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidlid" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("lid")%>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidUpdated" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Updated")%>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manufacturer" SortExpression="manufacturer" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrMan">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMan" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("manufacturer") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Caliber" SortExpression="caliber_gauge_bore" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrCal">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCal" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("caliber_gauge_bore") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grn/Wt" SortExpression="grains_weight" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrGW">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblGW" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("grains_weight") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="product_name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrProd">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProd" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("product_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="price" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrPrice ">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:c}") & "/" & Eval("units") & "<br/>(" & Eval("total_rounds") & ")"%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cost/Rnd" SortExpression="price_per_round" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrCR">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCR" runat="server" CssClass='<%# "Status" & Eval("stock_status")%>' Text='<%# Eval("price_per_round", "{0:c}")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function pageLoad() {
                        // does not completely work - the row styles remain after postback, but header styles disappear and responsive part does not work
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('[id$=grdHG]').footable();
                            $('[id$=grdHG]').trigger('footable_redraw'); // does absolutely nothing
                        });
                    }
                </script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        $('[id$=grdHG]').footable({
                            breakpoints: {
                                phone: 480,
                                tablet: 1024
                            }
                        });
                    });

                </script>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

The code-behind:

```
Imports AppCore
Imports AppCore.AppCore
Imports AppCore.AppCore.Xutilities
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class TestSearch1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub testBS3_PreInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
        HGSearch_Data.DBConnStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub grdHG_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grdHG.Load
        'If Not Me.tksm1.IsInAsyncPostBack Then 'NOTE a futile attempt here to see if this worked, it did not.
        grdHG.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
        'End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub grdHG_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdHG.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
            'vendor
            e.Row.Cells(0).Attributes.Add("data-class", "expand")
            'manufacturer
            e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes.Add("data-hide", "phone")
            'caliber
            e.Row.Cells(2).Attributes.Add("data-hide", "phone")
            'product
            e.Row.Cells(4).Attributes.Add("data-hide", "phone,tablet")


        ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            'todo

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub grdHG_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles grdHG.Sorting
        'todo for server side sorting
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the MasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SiteBS.master.vb" Inherits="SearchWebsite.SiteBS" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title><%: Page.Title %>- Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Scripts/FooTable-2/css/footable.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Scripts/FooTable-2/css/footable.metro.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style type="text/css">
        body { margin-bottom: 80px; }
        .panel-body { padding-top: 0; }
        .page-header { margin-top: 0; }
        .featuredImg { margin-bottom: 15px; }
        .StatusO { color: #990000; font-weight: bold; }
        .StatusI { color: #006600; font-weight: bold; }
        .StatusB { color: #ff9900; font-weight: bold; }
    </style>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <%-- NOTE: Footable won't work in UpdatePanel w/script reference here   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/FooTable-2/dist/footable.min.js"></script>--%>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test 115</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#myaccount">My Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">FaceBook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#login" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cph1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Copyright 2003-<%=Now.Year%> Test</p>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-btn btn-info btn pull-right ">Extra</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

All the Bootstrap code (header, footer, menus) works fine & the jQuery works fine after postback, the footable CSS theme works fine too except for the header row (TH) in the GridView table. 
I'm stumped!

ADDITION:
Here's my new code - I eliminated the MasterPage & the UpdatePanel as the culprits to why this only works on the first page load

ASPX:

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="TestSearch2.aspx.vb" Inherits="SearchWebsite.TestSearch2" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Test 2</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Scripts/FooTable-2/css/footable.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Scripts/FooTable-2/css/footable.metro.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <style type="text/css">
            body { margin-bottom: 80px; }
            .panel-body { padding-top: 0; }
            .page-header { margin-top: 0; }
            .featuredImg { margin-bottom: 15px; }
            .StatusO { color: #990000; font-weight: bold; }
            .StatusI { color: #006600; font-weight: bold; }
            .StatusB { color: #ff9900; font-weight: bold; }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/FooTable-2/dist/footable.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <div class="container">


                <%-- Set minimum column widths --%>
                <style type="text/css">
                    .hdrVdr { min-width: 80px; }
                    .hdrMan { min-width: 128px; }
                    .hdrCal { min-width: 88px; }
                    .hdrGW { min-width: 88px; }
                    .hdrProd { }
                    .hdrPrice { min-width: 108px; }
                    .hdrCR { min-width: 95px; }
                </style>


                <asp:GridView ID="grdHG" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="odsHGSearch" EnableViewState="False" CellPadding="1" AllowSorting="True">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor" SortExpression="vendor" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrVdr">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblVdr" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("vendor") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hididx" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("idx")%>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidlid" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("lid")%>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidUpdated" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Updated")%>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manufacturer" SortExpression="manufacturer" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrMan">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMan" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("manufacturer") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Caliber" SortExpression="caliber_gauge_bore" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrCal">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCal" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("caliber_gauge_bore") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grn/Wt" SortExpression="grains_weight" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrGW">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblGW" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("grains_weight") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="product_name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrProd">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProd" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("product_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="price" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrPrice ">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:c}") & "/" & Eval("units") & "<br/>(" & Eval("total_rounds") & ")"%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cost/Rnd" SortExpression="price_per_round" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrCR">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCR" runat="server" CssClass='<%# "Status" & Eval("stock_status")%>' Text='<%# Eval("price_per_round", "{0:c}")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>



                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        $('[id$=grdHG]').footable({
                            breakpoints: {
                                phone: 480,
                                tablet: 1024
                            }
                        });
                    });

                </script>



            </div>
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsHGSearch" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetLive_ItemsByPageSort" TypeName="AppCore.HGSearch_Data" SortParameterName="sortExpression" SelectCountMethod="CountHGSearchs">

...
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>


        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

NEW CODE BEHIND:

```
Imports AppCore
Imports AppCore.AppCore
Imports AppCore.AppCore.Xutilities
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class TestSearch2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub testBS3_PreInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
        HGSearch_Data.DBConnStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub grdHG_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grdHG.Load
        grdHG.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    End Sub

    Private Sub grdHG_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdHG.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
            'vendor
            e.Row.Cells(0).Attributes.Add("data-class", "expand")
            'manufacturer
            e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes.Add("data-hide", "phone")
            'caliber
            e.Row.Cells(2).Attributes.Add("data-hide", "phone")
            'product
            e.Row.Cells(4).Attributes.Add("data-hide", "phone,tablet")


        ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            'todo

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub grdHG_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles grdHG.Sorting
        'todo for server side sorting
    End Sub

End Class
```

This should help troubleshooting.

Comment: UPDATE: I've removed the UpdatePanel and it still does not behave properly (nothing changed). In addition, I removed the Async="True" as well. So there must be another conflict going on.

Comment: UPDATE: I added a more basic webform for testing above. I think I've found a suspect: The sortable links (that are generated when AllowSorting="true".   To test, I put in a submit button in the first column, which, when clicked, created a postback (full). The postback, per se, is not the problem, but the regeneration of the GridView is. I'm leaning towards the possibility that the footable script is somehow not able to "find" the GV when it's regenerated even though there are no JavaScript errors reported.

Comment: scratch that last comment - the GV is being regenerated by the button postback. The only thing left is the headerlinks (may be the culprit).

Comment: OK. I've ruled out the headerlinks, it is the .Sort method of the GridView that is causing all the problems here. The solution, I believe, is to create my own headers in the .RowCreated event of the GridView with events, and, instead of using the built in Sort method, change the parameters of the datasource with the column to sort and ASC or DESC and rebind the GridView that way.

Comment: When I put it back in the UpdatePanel, I get the original problem all over again :(   The footable script just won't initialize on the UpdatePanel!!!

Answer (score 2):

The same problem for me resolve using this.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
            $('.footable').footable();
        }

    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

MC9000 Your problem is that you lost your rendered table after a postback isn't?

I had the same problem and tried this on the bottom of the page:

```
        $('table').footable();

        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function () { 
            $(document).ready(function () {
              $('table').footable();
            });
```

What I understand as problem: after the postback the JS references are lost, so you have to put them back.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Footable scripts have an irreconcilable problem with the AJAX UpdatePanel which, as per them and MS, will not be supported nor fixed. In other words, they are not compatible and no workaround is possible without re-writing the footable scripts (which I won't even bother with attempting to edit).